# Define a register as a macro in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to solve a project in C (beginner - college level)  and I have a small problem in a function .

I have two registers defined as macros  :

```
#define register1 0x02004000
#define register2 0x02004200
```

I want to access to the content of the first register and put in it the content of the 2nd register.

I do  the following :

```
*register1 = *register2 + 2
```

But it won't work because "#define" defines the registers as ints .

So how can I access the registers with the use of #define ?

(It might be a bad proposition but I'm still learning C :D )

Comment: First you need to know what the size of the registers are, then cast your defines to a pointer of a type with that size. Then you can add values to them.

Comment: Thank you so it should look like #define register1 ((int *)0x02004000) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the constants to the appropriate pointer type.

So for example if each of these points to an `int`, you would do the following:

```
#define register1 ((int *)0x02004000)
#define register2 ((int *)0x02004200)
```

And technically, what you have aren't actually registers but memory addresses.  Registers are part of the CPU and don't have an address.

Comment: They're probably I/O registers, not CPU registers. These are often memory-mapped.

Comment: It would probably be best to use a type like `int32_t`.

Comment: I did ! I used uint64_t since we are working with 64 bits

Comment: You might also need to make them `volatile` to ensure they're actually written to. Like this: `#define register1 ((volatile uint64_t *)0x02004000`.  If you make something `volatile` then C knows that the value at this address can be changed by an external source and thus doesn't optimize it out of the code.